# How can I use two output wires as one?

Tags: circuit-design, wiring, bad-wiring

Sorry about the novice question.

At the moment I am using an op-amp (http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm224-n.pdf) to boost my analog load gauge sensor output.

The op-amp takes two inputs and gives one output.

[image: wiring]

If I wanted to remove the op-amp from my circuit, my sensor still has two outputs (`-`, `+`) but the next component (an ADC) in my circuit only has one input.

Is it possible to remove the op-amp and somehow connect my two wire sensor straight to my one wire ADC?
(involving zero new components if it can be helped)

---

Edit:

I was using two different load gauge, both with four wires, like this:

1) http://www.cnloadcell.com/uploads/20167365/r201612261601227200949.pdf

2 ) [https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61EL9dNvYlL.*SL1200*.jpg](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61EL9dNvYlL._SL1200_.jpg)
 https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B01CBGHCD8
 (sorry no datasheet)

[image: load cell]

And this is the ADC:
 https://www.mouser.co.uk/ds/2/405/ads1015-438945.pdf

[image: ads1015]

Yes this ADC does have differential input (2 pins) but this would mean I could only attach two sensors per board but I'd like to have four per board.

The load gauge sensor and the ADC are both powered and grounded by a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Probably not if you want any degree of accuracy.  Post part numbers (and preferably datasheets) for your sensor and ADC, and a schematic showing how the sensor is powered. Otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: It would depend on the information you have not explained. Is it a passive or active sensor? What output range does the sensor supply if active? What is the voltage or current range of your ADC? Typically you cannot simply drop out active components and expect to get the same results.

Comment: thanks, hopefully I've added the right information (see edit)

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot merely tie a differential pair of outputs like this together.

However, you may be able to connect one of the outputs to the ADC input, and either leave the other output unconnected, or connect it to a ground or other voltage reference.   Which is appropriate would depend on unspecified details of the sensor - typically, an *active* sensor would let you leave an output unconnected, while a passive one would need it connected.   A current mode output could be more complicated still.

Note that using only one side of a differential signal will halve the amplitude, and also greatly increase noise susceptibility - a major point of differential signalling is that added noise common to both sides is cancelled out when their difference is evaluated, but when only looking at one, you see the sum of the signal and the noise.

You are unlikely to get satisfactory results from a load gauge type sensor  using only half of the output, unless there are already electronics between the actual sensing element and the wires you are contemplating.

Comment: (my whole circuit uses a shared ground) my so it sounds like I could just use the `+` from the load gauge and put the `-` to common ground? (I'll compensate for the noise in code)

Comment: Unfortunately, the existence of a shared ground *does not* necessarily mean that it is okay to connect the negative/inverting differential output to it, *nor* that it is okay to leave it unconnected  You're going to have to analyze the actual circuit of whatever is driving it - detail that is missing from your question.  For a typical four-wire load cell you might look at the HX711 which has not only a suitable exciter and amplifier but the ADC as well, yielding a digital output.

Comment: Thanks. This is where my knowledge falls down, any recommended software for drag and drop drawing of circuits? (learning whilst doing it)